# Trying to get SalesForce to recognize an Attachment as a PDF

Tags: salesforce, jsforce

I am able to use sObject to put an Attachment onto one of my records.  The problem is that SF is not recognizing the file as a PDF but as a generic file.

```
      const base64data = await new Buffer.from(pdfBuffer).toString('base64');

      try {
        await conn.sobject('Attachment').create({
          ParentId: filename,
          Name: resumeFileName,
          Body: base64data,
          ContentType: fileType,
          Description: 'Resume Attachment',
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Attachment Error', e);
      }
```

When I look at the attachments of my record, the file does not have all of the options that a PDF file has (only download and delete)

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of your `fileType` variable? I think it needs to be `application/pdf` for Salesforce to recognize it properly.

Comment: I have tried both,  fileType = 'application/pdf' and I have tried ContentType: 'application/pdf' as well.  No change in the way the attachment was added (not as a pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in order for Salesforce to recognize the pdf correctly you need to have the content type set to `application/pdf` AND the name of the file must include the `.pdf` extension. This worked for me:

```
(async () => {

    const jsforce = require('jsforce');
    const fs = require('fs');

    var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
        instanceUrl : '...',
        accessToken : '...'
    });

    const pdfData = fs.readFileSync('./test.pdf').toString('base64');

    try {
        await conn.sobject('Attachment').create({
            ParentId: '0012300000RWedX',
            Name: 'My Test PDF.pdf', // <= Turns out the name has to have .pdf
            Body: pdfData,
            ContentType: 'application/pdf',
            Description: 'Testing PDF Attachment',
        });
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

})();
```